# I was trying type this cmd in neovim "CocInstall coc-python" and i got a error

Tags: python, vim-plugin, neovim

Btw, I'm on a WSL(Ubuntu) and i was trying to enter this command `:CocInstall coc-python` in neovim, and got this error:

```
[coc.nvim] Error on load extension from "/home/helloagrock/.config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-python": e.dispose is not a function
```

Answer (score 3):

`coc-python` is unmaintained, you can use `coc-pyright` or `coc-jedi`.

Comment: I installed it a few days ago and it works. I think it is because when you install coc-python, coc-jedi is also installed.